# How to work with build.gradle file in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, adb, oculusgo

After I make a change in the build.gradle file, what is my next step? I think there must be more steps I am missing…. compiling?? building ??  I am making these changes in Android Studio.

Not being that familiar with the build.gradle file, I am not sure what to do next. Any help would be most appreciated.

I want the change I made to the build.gradle file to have an effect on being able to install my project onto my Oculus Device.  Right now I get the "Requires newer sdk version #29 (current version is #25).

Answer (score 1):

after making a change in build.gradle, you have 2 different options, but they're the same thing :
you can click on the gradle sync button, then gradle will apply the recent changes you made or, as you can see in the blue text underneath, you can also make use of the `Sync Now` feature which will be displayed after any changes have been made.
[image: Gradle sync button]
Here's an example of the complete warning which is displayed after a change
[image]
after this, you can build/deploy your project or make changes in code as you need to, your dependencies have now been updated and will be available, assuming gradle syncs successfully

Comment: Why can't I add "Sync Project with Gradle File" to either my menu or to my toolbar in Android Studio 3.6.1?.  It shows up when I try File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > Menus and Toolbars.  Then I see it under "Main Toolbar". I then select it, click OK, but it never shows up on my Toolbar.  Did I not install something?

Comment: no idea unfortunately, i'm using the latest version of android studio, i guess it has changed since then